# Building NSObject to save ABRecordRef data local

Tags: iphone, ios, nsobject, abaddressbook, abrecord

I want to store the `Content` of a `ABRecordRef` in my own Application independent of the entry in the `AdressBook`. After crossreading through stackoverflow and the apple developers site i found this to be the best way:

If got that right, one would need a `NSCoding` conform `NSObject` subclass with all values of `ABRecordRef` and at least the functions `initWithABRecordRef` and `getABRecordRefFromPeopleData` (assuming one names his class peopleData), where `initWithABRecordRef` would fill all values from an `ABRecordRef` (if not null) into an instance of the own class and `getABRecordRefFromPeopleData` returns an `ABRecordRef` opaque type with the Data stored in an instance of the own class.

**My question to that:**

I wonder if someone out there already did that, because I can imagine, other people came to the exact same problem before. If so, getting hands on that class would be aewsome, if not i am going to give it a try on my own and load the results up here if wanted.
Maybe you even know a better way to do that?

If you did implement a solution, please share it. If you need the same, I'd appreciate working that out together.

**Edit:**

I now started working on the thing and (as i expected) i ran into some unclear problems.
As it comes to `kABStringPropertyType` values my concept is pretty straight forward. Small example:

```
@implementation RealRecord
@synthesize firstName; //NSString

- (id)initWithRecordRef:(ABRecordRef)record{

    //Single valued entrys
    NSString *contactName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    firstName=contactName;
    [contactName release];
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    //single value entrys
    self.firstName=             [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"firstName"];
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{
    [aCoder encodeObject:firstName forKey:@"firstName"];
}

- (ABRecordRef)returnABRecordRefFromRealRecord{
    ABRecordRef returnRecord =ABPersonCreate();
    ABRecordSetValue(returnRecord, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, firstName, NULL);
    return returnRecord;
}
```

This works fine. Now im not so clear with how to do the same thing with the `kABMultiStringPropertyType`.I made me a `NSMutableArray` emailList and went on like this:

```
- (id)initWithRecordRef:(ABRecordRef)record{

    //Multi valued entrys
ABMutableMultiValueRef email=ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonEmailProperty);
for (int i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(email); i++) {
    NSString *anEmail = [(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(email, i) autorelease];
    [emailList addObject:anEmail];
}
return self;
}
```

Now im not shure, how to do the rest of the tasks on the multi values. Can i just encode and decode the NSMutableArray like i did with the Strings or do i have to set a key for all of the emails in `emailList`?

And how do i get the damn thing back into the returnRecord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into using libsqlite3.dylib and creating a sql database that will access the flat files generated for all the properties.

Sample iOS project with sqlite3 library is here:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_7_Application

&
Detail on doing so with ABAddressbook for contact's multi-value properties here:

http://linuxsleuthing.blogspot.com/2012/10/addressing-ios6-address-book-and-sqlite.html